# Spring integration router behavior from 4.3.10.RELEASE to 5.1.5.RELEASE

Tags: spring, spring-integration

I have an application based on Spring Integration and a part of that application has the following config.

It worked fine for the version 4.3.10.RELEASE. But now I am trying to upgrade the version to 5.1.5.RELEASE and the application fails to start with the exception mention below.

I was able to resolve the issue with changing the config but I am wondering why this has been changed

Old config working in 4.3.10.RELEASE:

```
@Bean
public IntegrationFlow mainFlow(@Qualifier("initChannel") PublishSubscribeChannel inboundChannel, TaskExecutor taskExecutor,
                                StatusUpdater statusUpdater, MyTransformer myTransformer, MyFilter myFilter,
                                AbstractMessageRouter messageRouter, FinalHandler finalHandler, InlineHandler inlineHandler) {
    return flow -> flow.channel(inboundChannel)
            .channel(new ExecutorSubscribableChannel(Executors.newFixedThreadPool(2)))
            .publishSubscribeChannel(taskExecutor, spec -> spec.subscribe(flow1 ->
                    flow1.handle(statusUpdater, "handle"))
                    .subscribe(flow2 -> flow2.transform(myTransformer)
                            .filter(myFilter, "filter")
                            .route(messageRouter)
                            .handle(inlineHandler, "handle")
                    ).errorHandler(new MessagePublishingErrorHandler())
            );
}
```

Exception in the logs with above config for version 5.1.5.RELEASE:

> Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: The 'currentComponent' (messageRouter) is a one-way 'MessageHandler' and it isn't appropriate to configure 'outputChannel'. This is the end of the integration flow.
> at org.springframework.integration.dsl.IntegrationFlowDefinition.registerOutputChannelIfCan(IntegrationFlowDefinition.java:3088) ~[spring-integration-core-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
> at org.springframework.integration.dsl.IntegrationFlowDefinition.register(IntegrationFlowDefinition.java:3033) ~[spring-integration-core-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
> at org.springframework.integration.dsl.IntegrationFlowDefinition.handle(IntegrationFlowDefinition.java:1185) ~[spring-integration-core-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
> at org.springframework.integration.dsl.IntegrationFlowDefinition.handle(IntegrationFlowDefinition.java:1001) ~[spring-integration-core-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
> at org.springframework.integration.dsl.IntegrationFlowDefinition.handle(IntegrationFlowDefinition.java:979) ~[spring-integration-core-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
> at com.config.IntegrationConfig.lambda$null$1(IntegrationConfig.java:42) ~[classes/:na]
> at org.springframework.integration.dsl.PublishSubscribeSpec.subscribe(PublishSubscribeSpec.java:58) ~[spring-integration-core-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
> at com.config.IntegrationConfig.lambda$null$2(IntegrationConfig.java:38) ~[classes/:na]
> at org.springframework.integration.dsl.IntegrationFlowDefinition.publishSubscribeChannel(IntegrationFlowDefinition.java:255) ~[spring-integration-core-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
> at com.config.IntegrationConfig.lambda$mainFlow$3(IntegrationConfig.java:36) ~[classes/:na]
> at org.springframework.integration.dsl.context.IntegrationFlowBeanPostProcessor.processIntegrationFlowImpl(IntegrationFlowBeanPostProcessor.java:309) ~[spring-integration-core-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
> at org.springframework.integration.dsl.context.IntegrationFlowBeanPostProcessor.postProcessBeforeInitialization(IntegrationFlowBeanPostProcessor.java:117) ~[spring-integration-core-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
> at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyBeanPostProcessorsBeforeInitialization(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:414) ~[spring-beans-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar:5.1.7.RELEASE]
> at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1770) ~[spring-beans-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar:5.1.7.RELEASE]
> at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:593) ~[spring-beans-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar:5.1.7.RELEASE]

Updated config working for 5.1.5.RELEASE:

The processing happening in `inlineHandler` bean is now happening in a channel/flow of its own instead of being inline. I had to change the `messageRouter` bean route the message to default flow which was happening inline earlier.

```
@Bean
public IntegrationFlow mainFlow(@Qualifier("initChannel") PublishSubscribeChannel inboundChannel, TaskExecutor taskExecutor,
                                StatusUpdater statusUpdater, MyTransformer myTransformer, MyFilter myFilter,
                                AbstractMessageRouter messageRouter, FinalHandler finalHandler, InlineHandler inlineHandler) {
    return flow -> flow.channel(inboundChannel)
            .channel(new ExecutorSubscribableChannel(Executors.newFixedThreadPool(2)))
            .publishSubscribeChannel(taskExecutor, spec -> spec.subscribe(flow1 ->
                    flow1.handle(statusUpdater, "handle"))
                    .subscribe(flow2 -> flow2.transform(myTransformer)
                            .filter(myFilter, "filter")
                            .route(messageRouter)
                            //.handle(inlineHandler, "handle") // removed this
                    ).errorHandler(new MessagePublishingErrorHandler())
            );
}


@Bean
public AbstractMessageRouter messageRouter(@Qualifier("swift") MessageChannel messageChannel, MessageChannel defaultFlow) {
    return new AbstractMessageRouter() {
        @Override
        protected Collection<MessageChannel> determineTargetChannels(Message<?> message) {
            System.out.println(">>>>>> Determining channel");
            if(//some cond) {
                 return Collections.singleton(defaultFlow);
              }
            return Collections.singleton(messageChannel);
        }
    };
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I am wondering why this has been changed

Well, let's see that error message again:

> The 'currentComponent' (messageRouter) is a one-way 'MessageHandler' and it isn't appropriate to configure 'outputChannel'. This is the end of the integration flow.

Now let's take a look into the router and get its difference, e.g. from service activator:

https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/5.3.2.RELEASE/reference/html/message-routing.html#router-implementations

https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/5.3.2.RELEASE/reference/html/messaging-endpoints.html#service-activator

As you see there is a `mapping` for the router to determine the further channel to send the message to. In your old config:

```
 .route(messageRouter)
 .handle(inlineHandler, "handle")
```

You just had that unconditional mapping for the `default channel` providing this chain of methods. However in that old version we missed the fact that falling back to the default output is not a default (see `resolutionRequired = true` option). So, we can't make an assumption that end-users always want a fallback to the main flow back. More over it produces an impression that you always can configure router in the middle of the flow. Starting with version `5.0` we aligned `IntegrationFlowDefinition` with router nature and have introduced an option to make assumption explicit:

```
/**
 * Make a default output mapping of the router to the parent flow.
 * Use the next, after router, parent flow {@link MessageChannel} as a
 * {@link AbstractMessageRouter#setDefaultOutputChannel(MessageChannel)} of this router.
 * @return the router spec.
 */
public S defaultOutputToParentFlow() {
```

And there is a doc on the matter: https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/5.3.2.RELEASE/reference/html/dsl.html#java-dsl-routers

Comment: This is a very detailed answer, I thank you for it.